# Want to split data in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with lot of data. Data is copied  from an html file so it's in one cell when I paste. The data looks like this:

```
Cell A
---------------- 
row 1 ) Text: name of my text 
----------------
row 2 ) Link: link of my text
----------------
row 3) num: 34
----------------
row 4) Some text 
----------------
data Repeat 33858 row's.
```

any formula or way to convert this data or rearrange this data in sheet like this

```
       Cell A          |  Cell B         |  Cell C  |  Cell D   
-------------------------------------------------------- 
Row 1) Text            |  Link           |   num    |  Some text    
__________________________________________________________
Row 2) Name of my text | Link of my text | 34       | Some text
________________________________________________________
Row 3) Name of my text2 | Link of my text2 | 35       | Some text2
```

and more. I hope you understand my question and try to help me.

Comment: I guess you mean "Column" instead of "Cell" and "row" instead of "raw" ?

Comment: This question does not follow a good format for stackoverflow, as it does not include what you've attempted to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to say that you want piece of text from a website imported to Excel.

So go to the *data* tab > in the *get external data* > click on *from the web* > insert your link.

I hope i translated the words well to english, because not everything is the same in excell in other languages.

Comment: thanks i try your idea but its not work for me ... anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Main()

    ' decleration
    Dim rowSource As Integer, rowDest As Integer
        rowSource = 1
        rowDest = 2

    ' titles in destination sheet
    With Application.Sheets("Sheet2")
        .Range("A1").Value = "Text"
        .Range("B1").Value = "Text"
        .Range("C1").Value = "num"
        .Range("D1").Value = "Some text"
    End With

    ' loop through all rows in source sheet
    Do While Range("A" & rowSource).Value <> ""

        ' copy data to destination in sheet2
        With Application.Sheets("Sheet2")
            .Range("A" & rowDest).Value = Range("A" & rowSource + 0).Value
            .Range("B" & rowDest).Value = Range("A" & rowSource + 1).Value
            .Range("C" & rowDest).Value = Range("A" & rowSource + 2).Value
            .Range("D" & rowDest).Value = Range("A" & rowSource + 3).Value
        End With

        ' next group
        rowDest = rowDest + 1
        rowSource = rowSource + 4

    Loop

End Sub
```

Required from you:

- Create "Sheet2"
- In "Sheet1", your 33858 data go in Column A.

Comment: thanks dear .. but its not working for me i dont know why .. anyways thanks for help .. hope anyother code or thing will help me ..

Comment: Do you have all 33858 entries in a Column (Column A)? and Do you have a sheet called (Sheet2)?